# MVC 4 RenderSection() don't visualize defined section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project based on MVC 4. I am trying to use the @RenderSection("Footer", false) functon to visualize my footer, but it is not displayed. I will post two links to my Layout file and to my View file.

1. Layout link: http://pastebin.com/78cQE5vD
2. View link: http://pastebin.com/r5qewYi2

Comment: I will post a link to my Visual Studio solution. The project where I have this problem is called "PizzaVikiMVC4". The name of the Layout is "_LayoutPizzas.cshtml". The name of the View is "Pizzas.cshtml".

The link to my Visual Studio solution is: http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=b432dd91bc

If you have problems with some of the links please contact me in this thread.

Comment: I solved my problem. Maybe next time I will explain my problem in more details.